# Traffic Light Application Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am completely stuck and lost and need assistance. I am trying to develop a Traffic Light Application in Android Studio using Java. The goal of the application is to click a button and loop through the different traffic lights while displaying the different colors on the button corresponding to the traffic light with different text. The initial state of the application is set to be on the Red Light, which has the Red Light image corresponding along with the button being displayed red with the text "STOP." It then loops to green light showing the image of the green light lit up with the button displaying a green color and text stating "GO." It then loops to the Yellow Light with the yellow light image displaying the button color yellow with the text saying "WAIT." Finally, it loops back to the initial state of Red Light and keeps going in an infinite loop.

With that my thought process was to create 3 different arrays for each of the pieces: image, button color, and button text. Along with each array I tried to create a for loop for each array to loop through the array to display the corresponding piece. However, I'm running into issues looping through the images since they aren't a natural data type, and not sure how to define them. Plus, when I try looping through the text and colors it will loop to the first item but not through the rest of the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn = null;
    ImageView iv = null;
    ImageView redTrafficLight;
    ImageView greenTrafficLight = null;
    ImageView yellowTrafficLight = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialize();
        registerListener();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // assign button variable
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_changeLight);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_TrafficLight);

        redTrafficLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.red2);
        greenTrafficLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
        yellowTrafficLight.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

        btn.setText("STOP");
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


    }

    private void registerListener() {
        btn.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW};
            final String[] text = {"STOP", "GO", "WAIT"};
            final ImageView[] images = {redTrafficLight, greenTrafficLight, yellowTrafficLight};


            int current = 0;
            int currentText = 0;
            
            int i = 0;
            
            for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i++ ) {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(colors[current + 1]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                btn.setText(text[currentText + 1]);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
               
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: `current` always has the value of 0. You are not using `i` at all. Shouldn't it be `btn.setBackgroundColor(colors[i])` ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right just switched it out. I was using current on a previous version I tried and forgot to remove what I previously had. How would I loop through the images though since it's an ImageView and not and int?